# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'SumoSelect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sumoselect.js

I'm getting the above error message when trying to call the [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) function against a select option element on an aspx page.

I have the following references in my web page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.sumoselect.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

With the files taken from:
https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect/zipball/master

At present I have only included the following in my project from the download:

1. jquery.sumoselect.js
2. sumoselect.css

My jQuery is correctly locating one of the element with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    element = elements[i];
    name = element.id;

    if (name.match(/FieldId_3/)) {
      $(element).SumoSelect();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

However, when it reaches $(element).SumoSelect(); it produces the error "***0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'SumoSelect'***"

I'm very new to jQuery/Javascript, but have tried multiple permutations of trying to call this function and pass the object, however none have worked.

Any ideas to help me get it working?

I'll be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Why not just give the `<select>` tag a class, and then use `$('.my-custom-select').SumoSelect();` rather than looping through every element on the page. Also `element` will return something like `<div class="my-div">` and not a jQuery selector, like `.my-div` for example.

Comment: The error message you're getting would suggest that the SumoSelect plugin has not loaded.  Have you checked the console for errors?  Is the path to the sumoselect plugin correct?

Comment: What other resources do you include? Maybe there's another version of jQuery included.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you are using **jQuery**, why bother using Vanilla JavaScript to get DOM Elements, and iterate over all collection, only to get one element by its **id**? *(id property should be unique in the document)*

You can refactor your code and initialize your plugin only on the elements that meet the selector criteria:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#FieldId_3').SumoSelect();
});
```

If no elements meet the criteria, the plugin not will be initialized (safely), because jQuery return an empty **like-array** object.

And obviously, the element with **id** `FieldId_3` must be a **select** element, as mentioned here: https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to this and am bastarding code like there is no tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to run SumoSelect is, as the others have said, somewhat overkill, to put it mildly.

However, I have tested your code and it does work, assuming that the `jquery.sumoselect.js` file is in the same directory as the HTML file in question.

I would suggest, then, that your problem is that the `SumoSelect` jQuery plugin is not being found.

Once that error is fixed, however, you should run SumoSelect in the manner suggested by Nick R.

Answer (score -1):

(I work with Malieki and have picked this up, for completeness...) After a couple of hours trial and erroring, I found that when I comment out the code below, the sumoselect part starts working ok.
We where experimenting with Saplin.Controls DropDownCheckBoxes first and then found sumoselect but we left a control in the same aspx (for Saplin).

```
    <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="TypeCB" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TypeCB_SelectedItemsChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Size="7pt" font-family="Verdana" CssClass="txt_box"
    AddJQueryReference="True" meta:resourcekey="checkBoxes2Resource1" UseButtons="True" UseSelectAllNode="False">  
    <Style2 SelectBoxWidth="160" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="230" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" />
    <Texts OkButton="Ok" CancelButton="Cancel" SelectAllNode="ALL" SelectBoxCaption="Type" />
    </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

When this control is removed the sumo jquery stuff all starts working ok. 
I can only assume a conflict between them.
Thanks for the help though guys, we're both new to this.

Comment: we knew that script was the worst possible way to run sumoselect, it was just for debugging. we're using $('.my-custom-select').SumoSelect(); in the real code.